# How to set JAVA_HOME to point to a JDK installation?

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk

I installed `sun-java6-jdk`.

I need to find its home directory. `JAVA_HOME` must point to a JDK installation, not JRE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the `whereis` command to find where your JDK is installed.

```
whereis java
```

On my Ubuntu 12.04 install, OpenJDK has files located in `/usr/bin/java`, `/usr/bin/X11/java`, `/usr/share/java`, `/usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz`. I'm guessing the Oracle version is located in the same directories.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to add `JAVA_HOME` variable, you can do so by adding it to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory

Open `.bashrc` file using an editor. If you use nano then

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add the following 2 lines in your .bashrc file.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/
export JAVA_HOME
```

There may be other ways to install, but this is what I have followed always.

Comment: I like vim, but it isn't for novice users. Switching it to nano here.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I configured in my Linux system:

I downloaded JDK1.8.0_77 and by default the downloaded file is in the location (Downloads directory) i.e  `/home/user/Downloads`, unpacked the downloaded JDK to `/home/user/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_77` and then

1. Open Terminal and type,

   ```
   editor .bashrc
   ```

   write these 2 lines inside,

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_77
   ```

   (enter the path of your downloaded JDK)

   ```
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

   save the file
2. `source ~/.bashrc`
3. `echo $JAVA_HOME`

That's it :)

Comment: But where is the JDK package in the first place ?